# modal show by id when the button was click inside the php foreach function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button inside the `foreach` function of **php**. I have a modal which has an **id** corresponding to the button clicked. Now, what i want to do is when i click the button it **shows the modal by id** but the first button only works to show the modal and the other doesn't. what should i do? here is my code...

```
           <?php $count = 0;  ?>
                <?php foreach ($land_i as $li){ ?>
                <?php $count++ ?>
                    <tr>                             
                    <td><?= $li['date_approved'] ?></td>
                    <td><?= $li['status'] ?></td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal_<?= $li['lpf_no'] ?><?= $count ?>" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Select</button>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
          <?php } ?>
```

I try to use **count** to generate it's unique number from the button. I know it's non-sense because each button has a **unique id** already. Here's my modal...

```
                <div class="modal fade modal_<?= $li['lpf_no'] ?><?= $count ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                  <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                      </button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">In Progress...</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <h4><?= $li['lpf_no'] ?></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

that's it. hopefully there's someone gonna help me this one. Here's another thing... i try to put the **modal** inside my `foreach` function. it works but the modal destroy and the design of the page too. so i prefer to place it outside the foreach function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `data-target`. You append the count on to the end of the `data-target` in the loop (`data-target=".modal_<?= $li['lpf_no'] ?><?= $count ?>`), along with your modal itself: `<div class="modal fade modal_<?= $li['lpf_no'] ?><?= $count ?>` ... `</div>`. The problem is that `$count` does not reflect the **current** count; the loop has **already finished** by this point; `$count` now only refers to the last item.

Assuming you want a different modal for each item, you will indeed need to output the modals inside of a loop -- I'd actually recommend making use of a **second** loop for this, so as not to have to worry about things like closing your table:

```
<table>
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($land_i as $li) { ?>
    <?php $count++ ?>
    <tr>                             
    <td><?= $li['date_approved'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $li['status'] ?></td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal_<?= $li['lpf_no'] ?><?= $count ?>" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Select</button>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>

<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($land_i as $li) { ?>
    <?php $count++ ?>
    <div class="modal fade modal_<?= $li['lpf_no'] ?><?= $count ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
        ...
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This way you will end up with a different modal for each item, and they will all have the correct `data-target` reference. It also shouldn't break your formatting due to the closure of the `<table>` before starting the second loop.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  i already remove the count because it's useless. it was a great idea to create another loop for this. let me try your code.

Comment: i try modal inside the loop. it's functionable but the modal is hidden by a black screen which i can't click it.

Comment: The count's not useless as it gives a unique identifier to be used in the class name. I'm not sure about the black screen, but it shouldn't be present based on your above code. You do have `display: none` on your modal - that may be the culprit.

Comment: hands up for you man. Yeah, it's not useless but it's okay to remove the count because each button represent a unique id already and so with the modal too. anyway... thank you for having me this kind of idea. Now i can escape this kind of problem :).